# How i can to filter queryset by current user in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class SalonCarDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    salon = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Salon.objects.filter(owner=?))

    class Meta:
        model = SalonCarDetails
        fields = ["salon", "car", "price", "number_of_cars"]
```

CurrentUserDefault() doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write your own PrimaryKeyRelated field like that:

```
class SalonKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return qs
```

then you can filter qs by request.user, this will be called only on POST and PUT requests. You can then include it in your serializer

```
salon = SalonKeyRelatedField()
```

don't forget to include salon in your fields

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could see your views.py, but anyway I make some assumptions about it and put it in the class implementation scenario.

```
#
### views.py
#

# Django native libraries
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins, status
from django.db.models import Q

# your serializer and model
from .serializers import YourSalonCarSerializer
from .models import SalonCarDetails

class YourCustomViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin, 
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = SalonCarDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSalonCarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            return []

        lookups = Q(user=self.request.user)
        queryset  = self.queryset.filter(lookups)
```

Comment: >>> sr = SalonCarDetailsSerializer()
>>> print(repr(sr))
SalonCarDetailsSerializer():
    salon = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Salon.objects.all())
    car = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Car.objects.all())
    price = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, validators=[<function validate_positive>])
    number_of_cars = IntegerField(max_value=2147483647, min_value=0, required=False)
This is my serializer, i want ro filter only salon queryser in post by salon owner.